# Extent of Martyrdom Requirements in the Face of Anti-Religious Laws

Tags: halacha, minhag, martyr

There is a *halachik* principle brought down in the Talmud and codified in halacha known as *shaat hashmad* - a time of forced religious persecution. Generally, the rule is that any commandment of the Torah does not demand martyrdom for its observance with the exception of the 3 severe sins (idolatry, sexual crimes [i.e. adultery, incest, homosexuality, and bestiality], and murder) and the desecration of G-d's name (see Rambam [*Hilchot Yesodei Hatorah* 5:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=50)). However, at a time when there is a movement on the part of the non-Jewish authorities to destroy Jewish practices, then even minor commandments (or even mere customs) also demand martyrdom for their observance (see e.g. Rambam [*Yesodei HaTorah* 5:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=51)). What is the extent of this rule? Is a distinction made for when the existence of the entire Jewish people is threatened (e.g. in the days of Haman or the Holocaust) vs. just that of an individual ? Are there any other limitations that mitigate how widely this rule is applied - for example, is there any reason why it might not apply to being involved in *halachically* forbidden ceremonies (such as gay marriages or abortions) where the government might mandate the involvement as part of "anti-discrimination" statutes?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that for the past 2000 tears the Jews have become accustomed to periods of persecution, punctuated by interludes of peace. Nevertheless, my albeit limited forays through halachic literature show that the "shmad card" was rarely invoked.

Comment: Why is mandating abortion an anti-religious law?

Comment: Note that involvement in halachically forbidden ceremonies is [not necessarily](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/58950/2) halachically forbidden itself.

Comment: Related: http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/brooklyn/brooklyn-suit-aims-stop-barbaric-jewish-chicken-ritual-article-1.2283412

Comment: @DoubleAA As with virtually all halacha-violations, one could come up with scenarios of both l'teiavon or shmad, e.g. if the father doesn't want the baby and holds the doctor at gunpoint, it's not shmad. If the government objects to Torah law regarding abortion and demands doctors violate their conscience, it sounds like shmad.

Comment: I don't follow your latter case. It's where the government in an effort to wipe out Judaism's beliefs about abortion forces all Jewish doctors (or all Jews) in its jurisdiction on pain of death to perform abortions on random women? OK I guess that's shmad. Seems rather fantastical.

Comment: @DoubleAA Firstly, it's not at all clear that it would have to specifically target Jews to be considered shmad. Secondly, why would it have to be random women? Bloomberg in New York originally wanted to mandate abortion training for all MDs but backed off when there was a backlash and only made it the default training. Considering there have already been lawsuits forcing Christian photographers to service gay weddings, one could easily envision legislation that all OBs provide abortion on demand (not to mention that the USSR went so far as to ban Hebrew to achieve its secularist agenda).

Comment: @DoubleAA which is to say: fantastical indeed.

Comment: Exactly. You agree it's fantastical. Your tales about bloomberg are just wasting space on this page, not being relevant to the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA If we're discussing relevance and space-wasting, I'm  not sure why weakly thought out questions about the plausibility of hypothetical examples in hopefully theoretical questions don't themselves qualify for the descriptors.

Comment: Sure, but there aren't any of those here... Your stories of bloomberg aren't relevant bc there's no pain of death. Shmad doesn't apply bc no one is trying to kill the doctor. Perhaps or perhaps not the government may require one to eat pig for health reasons if they want to fly on an airplane. Ok. So Jews won't fly. We aren't all going to go kill ourselves bc of shmad! Perhaps a bank will be required to lend to Jews with interest to stay open. So it'll close. Ok. No Shmad. No deaths. Shalom al Yisrael.

Comment: In any event, the chances of any law being passed in a Western country whose aim is to wipe out Judaism's belief about anything is quite slim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25633/discussion-between-loewian-and-double-aa).

Answer (score 1):

You ask, “Is a distinction made for when the existence of the entire Jewish people is threatened vs. just that of an individual (e.g. in the days of Haman or the Holocaust)?”

In Halacha 1, Rambam says,

> Should a gentile arise and force a Jew to violate one of the Torah's
>   commandments at the pain of death, he should violate the commandment
>   rather than be killed,

from the expression “and force a Jew” it seems that the mitzvo of giving up one's life applies even if the life of one Jew is threatened.

You ask, “Are there any other limitations that mitigate how widely this rule is applied - for example, is there any reason why it might not apply to being involved in halachically forbidden ceremonies (such as gay marriages or abortions) where the government might mandate the involvement as part of "anti-discrimination" statutes?”

Halacha 3 states,

> All the above [distinctions] apply [only in times] other than times of
>   a decree. However, in times of a decree - i.e., when a wicked king
>   like Nebuchadnezzar or his like will arise and issue a decree against
>   the Jews to nullify their faith or one of the mitzvot - one should
>   sacrifice one's life rather than transgress any of the other mitzvot,
>   whether one is compelled [to transgress] amidst ten [Jews] or one is
>   compelled [to transgress merely] amidst gentiles.

From the text of Halacha 3 quoted above, it seems that to do the mitzvo of giving up one's life in the times of a decree, there must be a ruler who has the intention to nullify the Jewish faith or to nullify one of the mitzvos. The involvement which is expressly mandated because of "anti-discrimination" statutes seems not to meet the condition of nullifying the Jewish faith or one of the mitzvos.

Comment: I have to concur with Avrohom Yitzchok's interpretation of Halachah 3.  If, however, Berith Milah were prohibited by statute, as was attempted in a municipality in California recently, that would be an issue of Shmad, more so than, say, banning Halachic Shehitah, where you would have an option of just eating vegetarian.

Comment: [Arguments for eating meat on Yom Tov](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/54002/5) notwithstanding, at least there the counterargument can be made that not everyone *must* eat meat, and people can therefore refrain. Berith Milah, however, is an instance in which Shev VeAl Ta'aseh does not solve anything.

Comment: Baking a cake or arranging flowers for a same-sex marriage probably does not rise to that level. Officiating might, but even there the officiant isn't actually effecting Kiddushin, as Kiddushin cannot be effectuated in that circumstance. All it would be, in essence, is writing a(n Halachically) meaningless document and conducting a(n Halachically) meaningless ceremony. And in the case of such coercion, the penalty would seem to be civil, and it would be met with a strong communal defense and support. In other words, I don't think a single service provider would become a martyr.

Comment: "halachically forbidden ceremonies such as gay marriages" Which Biblical or rabbinic commandment does this violate?